# Appending data to current DF by pulling in data from another DF if condition is met

Tags: r, dplyr

First and foremost, thank you for taking your time to view my question.

I am running into the following problem:

I have some data that is grouped by quarter (looks something like below:)

```
Cust_ID   Date    QTR    Price    Action   Link_Cust_ID
  1      1/1/18  2018 Q1   23       NA       NA
  1      1/2/18  2018 Q1   22.2     NA       NA
  1      1/3/18  2018 Q1   12.1     2        5
  1      1/4/18  2018 Q1   14.1     5        NA
  3      1/1/18  2018 Q1   101      NA       NA
  3      1/2/18  2018 Q1   55       2        18
 ...      ...      ...     ...     ...      ...
```

(I have data for many quarters and many Cust_ID)

Essentially what I am trying to do is for each security in each quarter, if Action = 2, I want to include the Link_Cust_ID data (which we can say is stored in another df called Customers) for the remainder of the quarter.

I can't figure out how to go about pulling in data for the Link_Cust_ID **JUST UNTIL** the end of the quarter. Hopefully, looking for a solution using dplyr, but at this point, willing to take any sort of solution/help.

Ideally, the above table will look like:

```
Cust_ID   Date    QTR    Price    Action   Link_Cust_ID
  1      1/1/18  2018 Q1   23       NA       NA
  1      1/2/18  2018 Q1   22.2     NA       NA
  1      1/3/18  2018 Q1   12.1     2        5
  5      1/3/18  2018 Q1   10.1     NA       NA
  1      1/4/18  2018 Q1   14.1     5        NA
  5      1/4/18  2018 Q1   11.1     NA       NA
  3      1/1/18  2018 Q1   101      NA       NA
  3      1/2/18  2018 Q1   55       2        18
  18     1/2/18  2018 Q1   56       NA       NA
 ...      ...      ...     ...     ...      ...
```

Thank you very much. Please let me know if you want me to clarify something or have any suggestions on improving my question! #keeplearning

---

Below is an example of the Customer Table, which contains data for all customers.

```
Cust_ID   Date     QTR     Price   Action   Link_Cust_ID
  1      1/1/18  2018 Q1    23      NA         NA
 ...
  1     11/7/18  2018 Q4    66      NA         NA
  2      1/1/18  2018 Q1    3.2     NA         NA
 ... 
  2     11/7/18  2018 Q4    1.3     NA         NA
 ...
  5      1/1/18  2018 Q1    9.5     NA         NA
  5      1/3/18  2018 Q1    10.1    NA         NA
```

....

Essentially - the Customer table contains all of the Customer data.

The table in question ( where I want the data pulled to when action = 2 ) is a subset of the Customer table under some constraint

Comment: Would you give a reproducible example?

Comment: Hi @Jiaxiang, I sure would, but can you specify what you want to see? Do you want code to reproduce some sample data from the two tables?

Comment: `if Action = 2, I want to include the Link_Cust_ID data (which we can say is stored in another df called Customers) for the remainder of the quarter.` means you want to join table A with table B with some condition? Would you like to show sample data of the joined table (with key `Link_Cust_ID`).

Comment: @Jiaxiang I made some edits. hopefully they provide some sort of clarity

Comment: I go through it. wait for a moment.

Comment: Hi @yunpadewon, I confuse the link between `The table in question` and `Customer table `. Does the former's `Link_Cust_ID` join the latter's `Cust_ID`?

Comment: hey @Jiaxiang, it seems I might've not explained this quite well. let me think about how I can be more clear and perhaps repost a more clear version... i appreciate you trying to help however, thank yoU!